# Gamma in relative momentum in two dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum

I'm trying to find the momentum on the X-axis of a particle with mass $M$ and velocity $U$ in the direction of $\theta$.
The formula is $\gamma \cdot \text{mass} \cdot \text{velocity}$.

I know that:

$\text{mass} = M$

$\text{velocity} = U\cdot\cos(\theta)$

But what about the $\gamma$?
Is the momentum $P_1$ or $P_2$ (as shown below), and why?

$$P_1=\frac1{1-\frac{(U\cos\theta)^2}{c^2}}\cdot M\cdot U\cos\theta$$

$$P_2=\frac1{1-\frac{U^2}{c^2}}\cdot M\cdot U\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The momentum is neither of them, becuase you missed and square root in the $\gamma$.
The momentum is
\begin{equation}
p_{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{U}{c}\right)^2}} M U_{x}
\end{equation}

The reason of why it is that why is that it's just a convinient definition. The Lorentz factor
\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{U}{c}\right)^2}}
\end{equation}
where $U$ is the speed of the particle from an inertial system appears all the time whereas the one you proposed doesn't.

In Spetial Relativity we look for magnitudes covariant (i.e. transform the same way than the coordinates, doesn't matter) to Lorentz transformations, the one related to momentum is the *four-momentum*
\begin{equation}
p \equiv \gamma\,m (c, \vec{v})
\end{equation}
where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the particle form an inertial frame $S$ (I used the letter $v$ becuase the letter $u$ is used for the *four-velocity*)